# What is おもぴろかった

Tags: translation, definitions, register, diminutives

Saw this on twitter:

@Daigo19780408 昨日はお疲れ様でした！おもぴろかったです♪( ´▽｀)

What does おもぴろかった mean? I find words like this all over the place on the net, but I can't figure out what it means, and I can't find it defined anywhere.

Comment: A typo maybe? Could be おもしろかった。

Comment: @Calle It is not a typo.

Comment: And ヨロピク instead of よろしく

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Changing the consonant 's' (or 'sh' derived from it) into 'p' is sort of a diminutive. It  gives  the impression of cuteness/childishness. So the original form is `おもしろかった`. An English equivalent would be saying `doggie` for 'dog', etc. These forms are not at all the standard way of talking. A famous example is what came to be called ノリピー語 'Noripii-ish' in the 1980s, named after the idol 酒井法子 (sakai noriko), who pronounced many words in this way, for example, `うれぴー` for 'うれしい', etc.

If you change the 's' into 'ch' or 'sh', then it becomes a baby-ish talk: `おもちろかったでちゅ`, `おもしろかったでしゅ`, `うれちい`.