# body parts in childrens language

Tags: child-speech

At least in my country parents tend to give body parts cute or easier names when talking about them to children. Thus children use them too in their speech.
This is especially for sexual connoted body parts like penis, vagina, breasts and so on.
I tried searching for such words on jisho.org but it tends to be difficult.

Where could I find such word alternatives?
Is there a list?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/41439/5010

Comment: A partial list is listed at the "duplicate" question, but a more complete list is available on https://jisho.org/ [using the handle `#chn`](http://jisho.org/search/%23chn) for "children's speech", as noted in the comment on the answer there.

Comment: Ah great that's what I was looking for. Thanks @naruto and Earthliŋ